# Iterating over multiple indices with i > j ( > k) in a pythonic way

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

i need to iterate over a tuple of indices. all indices must be in the range
`[0, N)` with the condition `i > j`. The toy example I present here deals with
only two indices; I will need to extend that to three (with `i > j > k`) or more.

The basic version is this:

```
N = 5
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i):
        print(i, j)
```

and it works just fine; the output is

```
1 0
2 0
2 1
3 0
3 1
3 2
4 0
4 1
4 2
4 3
```

I don't want to have one more indentation level for every additional index,
therefore I prefer this version:

```
for i, j in ((i, j) for i in range(N) for j in range(i)):
    print(i, j)
```

this works perfectly well, does what it should and gets rid of the extra
indentation level.

I was hoping to be able to have something more elegant (for two indices that is
not all that relevant, but for three or more it becomes more relevant). What I came up with so far is this:

```
from itertools import combinations

for j, i in combinations(range(N), 2):
    print(i, j)
```

This iterates over the same pair of indices just fine. The only thing that is
different is the order in which the pairs appear:

```
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
2 1
3 1
4 1
3 2
4 2
4 3
```

As the order of what I am doing with these indices is relevant, I therefore cannot use this.

Is there an elegant, short, pythonic way to iterate over these indices in the same order that the very first example produces? Keep in mind that `N` will be large, so sorting is not something I would want to do.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could solve this generally as follows:

```
def indices(N, length=1):
    """Generate [length]-tuples of indices.

    Each tuple t = (i, j, ..., [x]) satisfies the conditions 
    len(t) == length, 0 <= i < N  and i > j > ... > [x].

    Arguments:
      N (int): The limit of the first index in each tuple.
      length (int, optional): The length of each tuple (defaults to 1).

    Yields:
      tuple: The next tuple of indices.

    """
    if length == 1:
       for x in range(N):
           yield (x,)
    else:
       for x in range(1, N):
            for t in indices(x, length - 1):
                yield (x,) + t
```

In use:

```
>>> list(indices(5, 2))
[(1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)]
>>> list(indices(5, 3))
[(2, 1, 0), (3, 1, 0), (3, 2, 0), (3, 2, 1), (4, 1, 0), (4, 2, 0), (4, 2, 1), (4, 3, 0), (4, 3, 1), (4, 3, 2)]
```

Comment: Maybe [`yield from`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) (supported from Python 3.3) could make the code more compact, like `yield from range(N)`

Comment: @lazzzis I thought about that, but it needs to do something to each value before yielding it

Answer (score 6):

You can use `product` from `itertools` if you don't mind the inefficiency of throwing out most of the generated tuples. (The inefficiency gets worse as the `repeat` parameter increases.)

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for p in ((i,j) for (i,j) in product(range(5), repeat=2) if i > j):
...   print p
...
(1, 0)
(2, 0)
(2, 1)
(3, 0)
(3, 1)
(3, 2)
(4, 0)
(4, 1)
(4, 2)
(4, 3)
>>> for p in ((i,j,k) for (i,j,k) in product(range(5), repeat=3) if i > j > k):
...   print p
...
(2, 1, 0)
(3, 1, 0)
(3, 2, 0)
(3, 2, 1)
(4, 1, 0)
(4, 2, 0)
(4, 2, 1)
(4, 3, 0)
(4, 3, 1)
(4, 3, 2)
```

---

Update: Instead of tuple unpacking, using indexing for the filter. This allows the code to be written a little more compactly. Only `my_filter` needs to be changed for tuples of varying sizes.

```
from itertools import product, ifilter
def my_filter(p):
    return p[0] > p[1] > p[2]

for p in ifilter(my_filter, product(...)):
    print p
```

Comment: that looks very clean indeed. thanks! will have to time how bad the inefficiency gets...

Comment: You can alleviate some of the inefficiency with `product(*[range(5-x) for x in range(3)])` (where `5` and `3` are modified as desired, of course), but that detracts from the elegance without really solving the issue entirely.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an approach with [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to have a generic number of *levels* -

```
map(tuple,(N-1-np.array(list(combinations(range(N),M))))[::-1])
```

Or a bit twisted one with same method -

```
map(tuple,np.array(list(combinations(range(N-1,-1,-1),M)))[::-1])
```

, where N : number of elements and M : number of levels.

Sample run -

```
In [446]: N = 5
     ...: for i in range(N):
     ...:     for j in range(i):
     ...:         for k in range(j):  # Three levels here
     ...:             print(i, j, k)
     ...:             
(2, 1, 0)
(3, 1, 0)
(3, 2, 0)
(3, 2, 1)
(4, 1, 0)
(4, 2, 0)
(4, 2, 1)
(4, 3, 0)
(4, 3, 1)
(4, 3, 2)

In [447]: N = 5; M = 3

In [448]: map(tuple,(N-1-np.array(list(combinations(range(N),M))))[::-1])
Out[448]: 
[(2, 1, 0),
 (3, 1, 0),
 (3, 2, 0),
 (3, 2, 1),
 (4, 1, 0),
 (4, 2, 0),
 (4, 2, 1),
 (4, 3, 0),
 (4, 3, 1),
 (4, 3, 2)]
```

Comment: aha! rearranging the output from `combinations`. looks interesting!

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Well its not meant to be a generator as I am using it as a NumPy array. So, to get the final output, we need to wrap it up with tuple : `tuple(map(tuple,(N-1-np.array(list(combinations(range(N),M))))[::-1]))`. That answers your question?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Or if you don't mind an array of indices as the final output : `N-1-np.array(list(combinations(range(N),M)))[::-1]`.

Comment: the drawback is that you create a list and have all the indices in memory; it's no longer a 'pure' generator, right? unfortunately `islice` can not handle negative steps...

Comment: @hiroprotagonist No, it's not a generator once we have wrapped it with `np.array()` there and thus creates all output indices in memory. Would that be a problem?

Comment: the only 'issue' is the memory (more a conceputal issue than a practical one...). because then i could just define: `def ijk(n, depth):
    lst = reversed(list(combinations(range(n-1, -1, -1), depth)));
    yield from lst` and get the indices from there. (same idea; no `numpy`).

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Yeah that should work, but still creates those indices in memory it seems.

Answer (score 2):

This is an approach based on the observation that it is easier to generate the *negatives* of the indices in the (reverse of) the desired order It is similar to the approach of @Divakar and like that has the drawback of requiring the list to be created in memory:

```
def decreasingTuples(N,k):
    for t in reversed(list(itertools.combinations(range(1-N,1),k))):
        yield tuple(-i for i in t)

>>> for t in decreasingTuples(4,2): print(t)

(1, 0)
(2, 0)
(2, 1)
(3, 0)
(3, 1)
(3, 2)
>>> for t in decreasingTuples(4,3): print(t)

(2, 1, 0)
(3, 1, 0)
(3, 2, 0)
(3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: yup, that is the same as the one in my comment in [Divakar's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41522251/4954037) (the one with `def ijk(n, depth)`), right? still like it!

Comment: ah, no, now i see the difference!

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Slightly different, since I am using a range which loops through negative values -- if it was exactly the same I wouldn't have posted. jon sharpe's seems best.

Answer (score -1):

a somewhat 'hacky' attempt using `eval` (just adding this for completeness. there are nicer answers here!).

the idea is to construct a string like

```
'((a, b, c) for a in range(5) for b in range(a) for c in range(b))'
```

and return the `eval` of that:

```
def ijk_eval(n, depth):
    '''
    construct a string representation of the genexpr and return eval of it...
    '''

    var = string.ascii_lowercase
    assert len(var) >= depth > 1  # returns int and not tuple if depth=1

    for_str = ('for {} in range({}) '.format(var[0], n) +
               ' '.join('for {} in range({})'.format(nxt, cur)
                        for cur, nxt in zip(var[:depth-1], var[1:depth])))
    return eval('(({}) {})'.format(', '.join(var[:depth]), for_str))
```

can be used this way and produces the right results.

```
for i, j in ijk_eval(n=5, depth=2):
    print(i, j)
```

the construction is not very nice - but the result is: it is a regular `genexpr` and just as efficient as those are.