# How to automatically create a nested for loop using a list of ranges?

Tags: python, nested-loops

I want to create a *nested `for` loop* that uses a list of integer numbers for the loops' ranges, just as follows:

```
a = [5,4,7,2,7,3,8,3,8,9,3,2,1,5]
for i in range(a[0]):
    for j in range(a[1]):
        for k in range(a[2]):
            for l in range(a[3]):
                ...
                   ...
                      ...
                          do_some_function()
```

Is there a way that I can do it automatically?

Comment: why do you want to use such a complex code? Its complexity will be `n^n`

Comment: Look into `itertools.product`, `map` and `*` sequence unpacking. But that's going to call `do_some_function` 304,819,200 times...

Comment: give a small example with a list of size 3.

Comment: `itertools.permutations(range(item) for item in a)`. Expect it to take time and resources.

Comment: Why so many downvotes? I don't understand. Is there anything wrong that I can fix?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I suspect you are asking how to implement a workaround solution you found to solve some problem, instead of asking about the main problem itself

Comment: The downvotes are, I presume, because a google search for "python nested for loop" finds this as the third result for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764579/python-nested-for-loops and you haven't shown any evidence of your attempt to actually address your own problem.

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to iterate over the permutations of the list's ranges with

```
for items in itertools.permutations(range(item) for item in a):
```

`items` will contain the sequence with one item from each range.

**Note:** The approach is very time and resource consuming. It might be good to consider if the concept your question is based on can be optimized.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what is the complexity of this algorithm?
So, I might ask my main problem instead of using this approach of using nested for loops.

Comment: The complexity is n^n

Comment: …or in simple words: it's hard to make it worse.

Comment: `itertools.product` would satisfy your needs.