# Python: How to have nested for-loops indexes that don't start from 0?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

So one issue I discovered with python is that it is not very user-friendly to create nested loops each with their own indexes.

How would I write the Python-equivalent of this Java code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length-2; i++){
    for(int j = i+1; j < array.length-1; j++){ 
       for(int k = j+1; k < array.length; k++){
```

Notice how I reference the counter value of the predecessor's for each nested loop. I tried using:

`for idx, val in enumerate(nums[:-2]):`

but it seems like `idx` will always start at 0 rather than start at the predecessor's index value. Is there a better solution besides maintaining separate counter variables?

Comment: I smell an XY problem here. What are you trying to solve? Often there are no 1-1 mappings between different languages (there is here), and there may even be a better pythonic way of solving the same problem that Java does not offer.

Comment: For reference, it isn't hard at all. `for i in range(len(arr) - 2): for j in range(i + 1, len(arr) - 1): for k in range(j + 1, len(arr)): ...` using the nested loops with `range` would be the obvious way of doing it.

Comment: this might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41521725/iterating-over-multiple-indices-with-i-j-k-in-a-pythonic-way

Comment: The goal is just to iterate through an array and do something with each triplet. Looks like instead of using an enhanced for-loop which references the current element directly, I just use the index values to reference the element from the array (ie array[i] vs val)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple to do that using `range` or `xrange`. Here's how you do it.

Java version:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length-2; i++) {
    for(int j = i+1; j < array.length-1; j++) { 
        for(int k = j+1; k < array.length; k++) {
```

Python version:

```
for i in xrange(0,len(arr)-2):
    for j in xrange(i+1, len(arr)-1):
       for k in xrange(j+1, len(arr)):
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

From [[Python.Docs]: Built-in Functions - enumerate(iterable, start=0)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) (**emphasis** is mine):

> The [__next__()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) method of the iterator returned by [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) returns a tuple containing a count (from *start* which **defaults to 0**) and the values obtained from iterating over *iterable*.

Example:

```py
num = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
start = 2
for idx, val in enumerate(num[start:], start=start):
    print("Index: {0:d}, Element: {1:d}".format(idx, val))
```

**Output**:

> ```py
> Index: 2, Element: 4
> Index: 3, Element: 6
> Index: 4, Element: 8
> ```

Comment: I would go for this version since if I'm not mistaken, enumerate returns an iterator, which is faster to iterate through than a list (returned by range). :)

Comment: @IMCoins: In *Py3* `range` also returns an iterator (behavior that in *Py2* is available via `xrange`). I don't think that iterators are faster than lists (iterator values are produced on the fly, while list is already there), the great advantage is memory consumption.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple.

```
for i in range(0,len(array)-2):
    for j in range(i+1,len(array)-1):
        for k in range(j+1,len(array)):
            print k
        print j
    print i
```

Answer (score 2):

Although completely answered, I just wanted to add an example with a nested `enumerate` to cover the original question. One important thing to have in mind is that the `start` parameter on the enumerate signature `enumerate(iterable, start=0)` won't skip the actual iterable. If you want to nest loops with enumerate in a scenario in which you do not want to re-use previous loops indexes, e.g., consider the `array=[1, 2, 3, 4]` for the original question, you *can't* just make:

```
for first_idx, first in enumerate(array):
    for second_idx, second in enumerate(array, first_idx + 1):
        for third_idx, third in enumerate(array, second_idx + 1):
            print(first, second, third)
```

As you will have the first iterations:

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 3
1 1 4
...
```

Instead, you have to:

```
for first_idx, first in enumerate(array):
    for second_idx, second in enumerate(array[first_idx + 1:], first_idx + 1):
        for third_idx, third in enumerate(array[second_idx + 1:], second_idx + 1):
            print(first, second, third)
```

It will correctly print:

```
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 4
2 3 4
```